# Is Spring Boot and Eclipse the same thing? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, eclipse, spring-boot

I am doing some research for a potential job coming up and I am trying to practice with AWS. If the company uses Spring Boot do I still need Eclipse? what are their relations to one another? Can i use Spring Boot and VSCode? or is Eclipse necessary?

Comment: Eclipse/VSCode is an IDE (integrated development environment), springboot is like a framework that helps you to create a web app, basically. You don't need any IDE to use springboot, they just have features that help in the development process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS is a cloud platform that enables you to rent platform (database) / infrastructure (virtual machne) utilizing pay as you go payments.

Spring Boot is a framework that many applications utilize as basic building block. A framework provides foundation to an application that you can build upon to meet your business functionality.

Eclise is an IDE where you develop / write code while VSCode is a text editor.

You use Eclipse / VSCode to write code. You use Spring Boot as framework as building block or you can say Spring boot provides some functionalities already so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Finally, once you have developed some code, you will use AWS to deploy / run your developed code.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I prefer to use VSCode so will I be missing out on anything major if I decide to go with VSCode over Eclipse?

Comment: Your question is fundamentally flawed - it's like saying "will I be missing out on anything major if I decide to use Paint over Photoshop?"; it depends.

Comment: VSCode is a text-editor, it may have some features to support Java development but not all. An IDE aids developers in lot of ways. It supports compiling, running from IDE itself. It is true that gap between VSCode and Eclipse is not that wide anymore, but in beginning prefer to use VSCode as you are learning to code and its important to learn syntax and symantics. IDEs will help you a lot in initial days but that breaks your learning curve. Better start with VSCode then switch to Eclipse once you have some proficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot is a Java Framework. Spring tool suite(STS) is an IDE for spring application development.

Eclipse is an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot is a framework in which we use java language to write code and it's a backend framwork to design backend application.

Eclipse/VsCode is the IDE to write code.